# Why tasks take longer when more workers are used

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am currently struggling to understand why single tasks are slower when more workers are used.
For example, with one worker, each task takes ~0.5s and with six workers, each task takes ~1s.
The computer I am working on has 8 cores so I was not expecting this change.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong, or why there is this difference?
Below is the code I am using:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

def compute():
    for _ in range(30000000):
        3*4

def gathered(list_):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=6, threads_per_worker=1)
    client = Client(cluster)

    graph = {}
    node_names = []

    for i in range(24):
        node_name = ('final_model', i+1)
        node_names.append(node_name)

        graph.update({
            node_name: (compute,)
        })

    graph.update({
        "gathered": (
            gathered,
            node_names
        )
    })

    client.get(graph, 'gathered')
    client.close()
```

Thank you for your time/help!

Answer (score 0):

Computers are complex.  For example you may have four physicals cores, which report at eight logical cores.  They are not fully parallel.  Also you may be stressing some other part of your machine, like memory hierarchy.  It's hard to tell.